# Need to control movement of UIImageView on UITableView in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

I have a `UIImageView` that currently moves to whichever row in a `UITableView` is selected by the user.  This functionality is working fine.  However, what I want to do now is also control its movement by using a button.  I have two buttons, one for going up one row, and one for going down one row.  Both buttons have different tag values but call the same `IBAction` method.  What I want to know is how do I move the `UIImageView` up/down by one row?  I presently have the following code which works fine:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_imageView];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{
        CGRect rect = [self.view convertRect:[tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] fromView:tableView];
        _imageView.frame = rect;
    }];

}
```

The above method works fine in moving the `UIImageView` to whichever row the user has selected.

How do I modify this code so that it strictly moves up exactly one row each time the up button is pressed, and down exactly one row each time the down button is pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the table view cell's indexPath from the last selected row in didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method in a NSIndexPath object.

```
 - (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_imageView];
  self.indexPath = indexPath;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{
        CGRect rect = [self.view convertRect:[tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] fromView:tableView];
        _imageView.frame = rect;
    }];

}
```

Process the indexPath in your button action method to see if the above/below cell will be in same section,in which case increment/decrement the row and if in other section, you might want to calcuate new indexPath.

```
-(IBAction)btnActn:(id)sender{
    if(btn.tag ==0){
     self.indexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.indexPath.row+1 inSection:self.indexPath.section];
    //Put animation code or call animation function 
    }
}
```

And then get the rect of one cell above or below's frame using the same method you already are using and translate the _imageView's location to the new location.